# jquery fire event after timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've implemented auto page scrolling using the jQuery plugin [datatables](http://datatables.net).

I'm attempting to add two buttons, one that stops the auto scrolling and one that starts it again.  I've gotten this working, but I want it to begin scrolling again if the page has been stopped for a period of time.  Here is what I have tried:

```
var refreshRate = 5;
var totalPages = 0;
var currentPage = 0;
var upTime = 0;

$('document').ready(function(){
var interval = window.setInterval('$("#start").click()',refreshRate);

    $("#start").click(function(){
        function start(){
            clearInterval(timeout);
            $("#stop").show();
            $("#start").hide();
            currentPage = table.api().page.info().page + 1;
            totalPages = table.api().page.info().pages;
            table.api().ajax.reload(function(json){

                if (currentPage != totalPages){
                    table.api().page('next').draw(false);
                }
                else{
                    table.api().page('first').draw(false);
                }
            });

            upTime = upTime + (refreshRate / 1000);
            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = setInterval('$("#start").click()', refreshRate);
        }
        start();
    });

    $("#stop").click(function(){
        $("#stop").hide();
        $("#start").show();
        timeout();

        clearInterval(interval);

    });

//call start on doc ready to auto start scrolling
    start();

    function timeout(){
        var timeout = window.setInterval(function(){


            start();
        }, 10000);
    }
});
```

As you can see I am attempting to call the start() function embedded within the button click after a 10 second timeout.  I am also getting a TypeError when I call start() at DOM ready to begin page scrolling.

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

But besides the error it scrolls as it should.
Any assistance?

Comment: For one, your `start()` function should not be in the `.click()` event. Second, you cannot access the variable `timeout` from anywhere because it's scope is within `timeout()`.

Comment: yeah, it does behave how intended however.  I haven't been able to fire the click event without the above start function.  Any ideas there?  `$("#start").click();` in the same spot as my `start()` call doesn't work, not sure how to do that.

Comment: Can you create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with all of your code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having issues with function scope. Your code that called `start` towards the bottom did not have `start` in its scope since you defined it inside the `click` handler. Also, `timeout` was outside of the scope too, which would cause the interval to go on forever:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var timeout,
        interval = window.setInterval('$("#start").click()',refreshRate);
    function start(){
            clearInterval(timeout);
            $("#stop").show();
            $("#start").hide();
            currentPage = table.api().page.info().page + 1;
            totalPages = table.api().page.info().pages;
            table.api().ajax.reload(function(json){

                if (currentPage != totalPages){
                    table.api().page('next').draw(false);
                }
                else{
                    table.api().page('first').draw(false);
                }
            });

            upTime = upTime + (refreshRate / 1000);
            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = setInterval('$("#start").click()', refreshRate);
    }

    function timeout(){
        timeout = setInterval(function(){
            start();
        }, 10000);
    }

    $("#start").click(function(){            
        start();
    });

    $("#stop").click(function(){
        $("#stop").hide();
        $("#start").show();
        timeout();    
        clearInterval(interval);

    });

    //call start on doc ready to auto start scrolling
    start();    
});
```

Comment: this solved the problem exactly. much appreciated. I see what I did wrong!

Comment: You can read up on this more in the Mozilla docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Comment: Only issue is the timeout only works on the first stop, if repeated it begins again every 3 seconds or `refreshRate`